# How to remove succeeding items in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Is there a way to remove items in a range in list? For example:

```
a = ['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

How can I remove items from `'jumped'` to the last item? I know in advance that `'jumped'` only occurs once in my list.

Comment: Your logic isn't well defined. What happens if your search string is "the" instead of "jumped"? We need more information / detailed assumptions.

Comment: sorry for being vague.I am using BeautifulSoup and after finding the text, it gave me a paragraph. i want to cut the paragraph starting from a unique string up to the last string in the list.

Comment: That's interesting, but it doesn't answer the question I'm asking for clarification.

Comment: so in this example, the "jumped" which is my search string is a unique string.I will see to it that my search string will always be unique(unrepeated). I just want a way to remove succeeding items starting from that unique string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the string occurs only once, you can use `list.index` and then use this with list slicing:

```
a = ['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']

idx = a.index('jumped')
res = a[:idx]

print(res)

['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python del supports slicing

you can do like...

```
del a[4:]
```

Output :  ['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox']

Comment: This isn't generalized. How do you calculate `4`? If you use `list.index` to calculate `4`, how do you deal with repeated items?

Comment: @jpp Agreed !!, I just try to give an idea of slicing deletion.